# trouble deploying full stack application on heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, mern

I have made a full-stack app with react js and node js with express and MongoDB but I am having a little bit of difficulty deploying I first tried to deploy the front end but I was getting the invalid host header coming up when I tried to deploy in Heroku its been tested and works fine in the dev environment.

But also my application has two separate git repos one for the back and one for the front end and every tutorial I have seen to deploy they always have the client in the same folder as the server.

Can someone either tell me how to deploy or point me in the right direction on how to deploy.

Comment: I prefer netlify for frontend and heroku for backend ( node )

Comment: @NishargShah why do you prefer to do it like this?

Comment: because netlify is too easy to use and it's linked with GitHub repo and Heroku is best for PHP and node, with simple commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do for React/Express/Node/MongoDB is,

1. build your frontend app first by using "npm run build". This will create a build folder under your app folder.
2. move your "build" folder to backend app folder.
3. update your backend app to use "app.use(express.static('build'))".

Then you can push your code to git and Heroku and try to deploy it.

There should be some tutorials available on Heroku website.

Comment: This makes more sense thanks for clarifying do I need to upload the rest of the front end app or is the build  folder all thats needed in the backend app

Comment: have you used other platfomrs for deployment too

Comment: No, I generally use Heroku only.